# react not making api call only on routes with props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my app, there is a Header that is imported at the top of the component with 3 link dropdowns. Everywhere on my site, these dropdowns work except one dropdown does not work on pages where I pass a prop id to the router.

The routes where the problem happens:

```
<Route path="/service/:name" render={(props) => <ServiceShow {...props} />}/> 
<Route path="/employee/:userId" render={(props) => <EmployeeShow {...props} />}/> 
<Route path="/class/:id" render={(props) => <ClassShow {...props} />}/>
```

The below code is the dropdown code. `this.fetchCategories()` and `this.fetchClasses()` return the proper information. From adding in logs the problem is in the `fetchCatefories()` function, the call never makes it to the API but only on the routes above. I am guessing I am doing something that is against how React works but am stumped.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.fetchEmployees()
  this.fetchCategories()
  this.fetchClasses()
}


fetchCategories = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/categories`)
  const initialCategories = await response.json()
  const services = initialCategories
  this.setState({
    services
  })

}
fetchClasses = async() => {
  console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^1Clases IN HEADER")
  const response = await fetch(`/api/classes`)
  const initialClass = await response.json()
  const classes = initialClass
  console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^Clases IN HEADER", classes)
  this.setState({
    classes
  })
}

fetchEmployees = async() => {
  console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^1Employee IN HEADER")
  const response = await fetch(`employees`)
  console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^2Employee IN HEADER", response)
  const initialUser1 = await response.json()
  console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^3EMPLYEES IN HEADER", initialUser1)
  const employees1 = initialUser1
  console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^EMPLYEES IN HEADER", employees1)
  this.setState({
    employees: employees1
  })
}
```

Comment: `componentWillMount()` is deprecated.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix the problem

Comment: I  dont see where you are calling this.props.id. Also is the DropDown  a HOC? Could you include how the drop down is being called by the route that is not working?

Comment: "...dropdowns work except one dropdown does not work on pages where I pass a prop id to the router". Where are any dropdowns in your snippets? Where is the router? Please include all relevant code.